Creating REST API with custom "x-myvalue" in header
Super simple ApiController:
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpPost]
  public IActionResult DoStuff([FromHeader] string X-SomeValue)
  {
     return Ok();
  }

}

This does not compile, as X-SomeValue is not a valid parameter name.
The easiest is just call it XSomeValue, but AFAIK best practise is use X-.
How can I use X-SomeValue in the header?

To use names that are not valid C# identifiers, you must specify the name explicitly like this:
  [HttpPost]
  public IActionResult DoStuff([FromHeader(Name = "X-SomeValue")] string xSomeValue)
  {
     return Ok();
  }

More information on the FromHeader attribute's Name property:

FromHeaderAttribute.Name Property


Perfect! Just what I wanted

btw, the OpenAPI syntax is lowercase x-.  https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3#specification-extensions
